# Route teamviewer desktop client through SSH tunnel in PuTTY?

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty, ssh-tunnel, teamviewer

I'm trying to route the TeamViewer desktop client through an SSH tunnel I've made using a home server (with DD-WRT) and PuTTY on my end. In PuTTY, I chose port 1080 to Dynamic range, so it works fine and dandy as a socks proxy in my web browser.

However I know SSH is for more nice stuff. I managed to use socat thanks to someone else who helped me here on this group for routing GMail's IMAP server to my Outlook client, but alas, IMAP and SMTP/POP3 servers are well-known. Teamviewer's servers are a lot and I bet they use dynamic port ranges locally, making the issue harder to tackle.

TeamViewer has an option to set a proxy, but it doesn't use the socks proxy. I assume it must use an HTTP proxy, but in my end I'm behind a very restrictive proxy server (with authentication) which doesn't let me connect to TeamViewer's servers, and it's also the reason why I had to use socat (since it allowed to provide credentials).

Anyways, anyone have any idea on what can I use, either socat or another solution (I have cygwin, if it helps) to help me use the TeamViewer client? I tried logging on the web system but when I try to connect it launches the desktop client, so it's a no-go :(

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, for those interested, I managed to do it, albeit with a trial app, it's something at least:

1. Download proxifier portable, go to Profile -> Advanced -> Proxification Engine -> Change Hook Type to Module Copy.
2. STOP TeamViewer Service (Start -> Run -> services.msc)
3. Start TeamViewer THROUGH the Start Menu shortcut. Proxifier will hook into TeamViewer's startup client AND in consequence to the service because it is started by TeamViewer and not the service console, allowing it to be hooked correctly.

Enjoy! :D

Answer (score 14):

Yes.  Goto Extras->Options->General ...click on "Configure" for proxy settings.  Change to manual proxy and for Proxy IP enter socks5://127.0.0.1 and the port you are using.  Obviously change the 127.0.0.1 to whatever IP you are wanting to use.

Comment: Fantastic! The socks5:// protocol prefix was the missing piece.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer

Comment: what is proxy port or how do we find one?